# Crash when "Create Data Binding" in Blend for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime, blend-2012

Blend for Visual Studio 2012 always freeze when I click on "Create Data Binding".
I am using Windows 8 Professional 64 bit on MacBook Pro.
Have anyone experience the same error I am having?

Comment: I am having this problem too. Not on a MacBook either. I believe the cause is because I changed display resolution settings on my Surface RT, which then synced over to my other machines. A past bug with the RC tools was that remoting exceptions would occur whenever the display settings were changed, with no workaround other than a reinstall. I'm going to try the reinstall soon and I'll see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution.
The Expression blend freez, because of "Create Data Binding" dialog display out side visible area and it block user interaction.
Here is the solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/6f251999-9549-41dc-86b1-25388b977b49/?prof=required

Answer (score 0):

Using visual designer, either Blend or the built in Visual Studio is sometimes problematic. Here I would recommend just creating the binding directly in designer. It's easy, fast and you got complete control over it.

[Data binding overview (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh758320.aspx)

Comment: Just found a solution.
[Create Data Binding dialog display out side visible area](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/6f251999-9549-41dc-86b1-25388b977b49/?prof=required)